# Generating triangular series sequence in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Want to achieve the following triangular series sequence with MySQL query :-

**Expected output :-**

```
Sequence
    1
    2
    2
    3
    3
    3
    4
    4
    4
    4
    5
    5
    5
    5
    5
 ... and so on
```

I tried to apply the intended logic in python and it worked fine.

```
for i in range(1,6):
    for j in range(1,i+1):
        print(i)
```

When i researched I saw looping is quite easy to do in PL/SQL. I wanted to know in MySQL how can we achieve this without using Stored Procedure ?

Comment: cte for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS ( SELECT 1 number
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT number + 1 FROM cte WHERE number < @number)
SELECT t1.number
FROM cte t1
JOIN cte t2 ON t1.number >= t2.number
ORDER BY t1.number;
```

where `@number` is upper limit.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c5772ebc36706b20a5d4e5648ed8b4d1)

If `@number` is less than 1 then only one row with `1` is returned. If `@number` is decimal it is rounded up (3.01 will give values up to 4).

If `@number` is high then adjust `@@cte_max_recursion_depth` session variable value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive CTE for this . . . and do it all in a single query:

```
with recursive n as (
      select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5
     ),
     triag as (
      select n, 1 as i
      from n
      union all
      select n, i + 1
      from triag
      where i < n
     )
select *
from triag;
```

Recursive CTEs are standard SQL, so this idea works in both MySQL and Oracle.  However, there are nuances to the syntax depending on the database.

Comment: works fine @Gordon Linoff, but here you seem to have hardcoded the recursive n CTE from 1 to 5 using union. What if the number is dynamic ?